# Padrino custom application extension

Tags: sinatra, padrino

I have a Padrino project made of several applications and I want to write a module to avoid repeating this in every sub app:

```
class MySubApp < Padrino::Application
  register Padrino::Rendering
  register Padrino::Helpers
  register Padrino::Warden

  enable :sessions

  before do 
    env['warden'].authenticate!
  end

  get '/debug' do
    ...
  end
end
```

Instead I would like to write just this:

```
class MySubApp < Padrino::Application
  include MyAppsExtension
end
```

I've been trying different things defining the repeated code within a module and also nested within the Sinatra module, but I still cannot get the right way to define this.

Also I tried making an intermediate class between my apps and Padrino::Application, but I get many errors and the Sinatra DSL functions (before/get...) are lost.

How can I write such extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make `MyAppsExtension` an extension then when it is registered the `registered` method is called and passed the actual app. In this method you can set up your app how you’d like, including registering other extensions.

```ruby
module MyAppExtension

  def self.registered(app)
    # use 'app' as you would use 'self' in your app
    app.register Padrino::Rendering
    app.register Padrino::Helpers
    app.register Padrino::Warden

    app.enable :sessions

    app.before do 
      env['warden'].authenticate!
    end

    app.get '/debug' do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

You can then use this like you would any other extension:

```ruby
class MySubApp < Padrino::Application
  # 'register', not 'include'
  register MyAppsExtension
end
```

Note that you don’t need to make your extension module a subclass of the `Sinatra` module. Some extensions do, including those in the examples of the Sinatra docs. If you want to make your extensions available in classic style Sinatra apps (without needind to call `register`) you would need to call `Sinatra.register MyExtension`, but this isn’t necessary for modular apps.

Comment: Looking at the code https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/faf2efc670bf4c6076c26d5234c577950c19b699/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1386, I noticed that `register` can take a block. Do you have a reference of actual good use of blocks? I tried to use it for my extension-parameters, but the result was extremely ugly.